# the gcp auth plugin is deprecated, how to skip this error?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have install gke on a test account and configured the cli.

```
kuebctl get pods
```

is giving below warning.

```
W0916 17:23:58.063534   67381 gcp.go:119] WARNING: the gcp auth plugin is deprecated in v1.22+, unavailable in v1.26+; use gcloud instead.
To learn more, consult https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke
No resources found in default namespace.
```

But I already installed the gcloud-auth-plugin

```
sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk-gke-gcloud-auth-plugin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
google-cloud-sdk-gke-gcloud-auth-plugin is already the newest version (402.0.0-0).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 61 not upgraded.
```

But still why I am getting this warning?
Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
gke-gcloud-auth-plugin --version
Kubernetes v1.24.0-alpha+f42d1572e39979f6f7de03bd163f8ec04bc7950d
```

Comment: Did you do the "Verify installation" and "Run kubectl with the new plugin prior to the release of v1.26" steps on that page?

Comment: yes I did, but still same

Comment: You'll very likely have to change the `exec:` inside your `$KUBECONFIG` to have it switch over to use `gcloud`; it may be easier to just ask gcloud to make you a new kubeconfig, unless you already have a _lot_ of customizations therein

Comment: i performed all the steps in this link as shown in warning message, https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke   but same issue, Can you please elaborate what step you are suggesting

Comment: @Kalel can you run the below command and send the output for further analysis:

 kubectl get namespace

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure you've installed the plugin and set:

```
USE_GKE_GCLOUD_AUTH_PLUGIN=True
```

For your environment. Then run:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials ...
```

The warning should go after that when running any kubectl commands.